# Obtener datos de un Fragment/Activity para pasárselos a la activity principal sin que esta pierda los datos que ya se hubieran introducido

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragment, activity

Tengo una activity en la que recojo varios parámetros (descripción, título, fechas...) y cuando pulso un botón de Guardar funciona bien. Hasta aquí todo correcto.

Yo quiero guardar la dirección que el usuario introduzca y aparezca en el marcador que tendré cuando implemente un mapa.

La duda que tengo es, si hacerlo a través de un mapView en la activity principal y solo debería guardar el nombre de la dirección en una variable.

O, por el contrario, tener botón “elegir dirección”, que me abra una nueva actividad/Fragment que implemente un mapa, y al haber seleccionado la dirección con el marcador, devuelva Esa dirección a la activity principal cuando pulse “guardar”, que no se ha terminado/ cerrado aún y debería contener los datos que el usuario hubiera introducido. Esta actividad tendría dos botones de guardar/cancelar y en el caso de que los pulse habría que volver a la actividad principal con/sin la dirección (en función de si ha seleccionado o no una dirección), y que los datos que hubiera antes siguiesen en sus respectivos editText.

Me gusta más la segunda forma, pero no sé cómo mandar los datos desde la nueva activity/fragment sin cerrar la activity principal para no perder los datos que el usuario hubiera introducido ya.

¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En la [documentacion](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=es) tienes información de cómo obtener el resultado de una Activity que has lanzado.

Comment: La segunda opción es mas factible ya que puede llamar a la activity del mapa desde otros lugares de tu aplicación. Para realizar lo que planteas en el segundo punto es bastante sencillo. Solo tienes que utilizar startActivityForResult() para llamar a la activity del mapa y en la actividad donde quieres obtener los datos usar el metodo onActivityResult() Te dejo un enlace de la documentación oficial donde explican con ejemplo como realizar lo antes descrito: [Cómo iniciar la actividad](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=es#StartActivity) y [Cómo recibir el resultado

Comment: Agrega lo que has realizado por favor, revisa [ask], saludos